# Non-java resources disappear from class package after maven packaging

Tags: java, maven, resources, maven-resources-plugin

I'm trying to create a Spring project structure where I have my HTML templates stored in the same src/main/java package (in Tapestry-like way), so the structure basically looks like this:

```
src/main/java
            -org
               -example
                  -views
                     -pageOne
                         PageOneController.java
                         Template.html
                     -pageTwo
                         PageTwoController.java
                         Template.html
```

However after packaging a WAR while using Maven I get a structure like this:

```
WEB-INF/classes
              -org
                 -example
                    -views
                       -pageOne
                           PageOneController.class
                       -pageTwo
                           PageTwoController.class
```

So the `.html` files are ignored and obviously nothing works.
I tried to configure `maven-resources-plugin` to copy those resources like this:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>*/**.html</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>*/**.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

but to no avail.

How do I configure my project to copy non-java files from `src/main/java` into the final output?

Comment: Java source files belong into `src/main/java` and resource files like `.html` files belong into `src/main/resources` (follow convention over configuration).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem was with maven modules. I have declared `resources plugin` in the main `pom.xml` instead of the module's `pom.xml` which lead to the configuration issues.